# MySQL statement, JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have these tables :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't know how I can write a statement, that takes emails from Table "Firm", that have `Location_id = '1'` and `Category_id = '130';`
I know that I should use JOINs, but I'm not sure how to go from there.

Comment: you need to try something before posting questions, that's one of the easiest joins you might face in your life

Comment: I tryed something  SELECT Firm.email FROM Firm INNER JOIN FirmID ON FirmID.location_id = '1' AND FirmID.category_id = '130';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Firm.email 
FROM Firm 
INNER JOIN FirmID ON Firm.firma_id = FirmID.firma_id 
WHERE FirmID.location_id = '1' 
AND FirmID.Category_id = '130'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
SELECT f.email 
FROM Firm f 
WHERE f.firma_id = 
(
    SELECT ff.firma_id 
    FROM FirmID ff 
    WHERE ff.location_id = 1 
    AND ff.category_id = 130
)
```

Using an inner select.

But using JOINS is in the long term the way to go, what have you tried and what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as doing the following:

```
SELECT email
FROM Firm, FirmID
WHERE Firm.firma_id = FirmID.firma_id
AND FirmID.location_id = 1
AND FirmID.category_id = 130;
```

It does a join behind the scenes, but can be a bit clearer to understand than using the JOIN keyword.

Comment: I really wouldn't advise to use that syntax instead of the join one.

Comment: Could you explain why?  My understanding was that it was no less efficient than explicitly using the JOIN keyword, as SQL still does a join.  Thanks

Comment: for example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your point.  However, I think the outcome of that particular question is that the two are synonyms - the advantages of either option (in a case as simple as this) are stylistic. I was just trying to help the OP understand what a join meant :-)